# How to create Mock to a class that implement an abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking

I have the example above and i need to decouple the code to ease the tests, how i can do this to can test using mock?

```
public sealed class XCommand : BaseCommand
{
    public IResult Author()
    {
        //DO SOMETHING AND RETURN BASE.

        return base.run();
    }        
}

public abstract class BaseCommand
{
    public virtual IResult Run()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        using (Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo })
        {
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

            String error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            String output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim();

            return new Result()
            {
                Error = error,
                Output = output
            };
        }
    }
}

sealed class Result : IResult
{
    public String Error { get; set; }

    public String Output { get; set; }
}
```

there are a lot of class that will inherits the class BaseCommand and i need to test every class individually, so how i can decouple this code to be possible make this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *"How do i de-couple this code"*? What isn't decoupled right now?

Comment: I need to create a mock to test somenthing like this. XCommand command = new XCommand();, but here always will try to execute a process, and sometimes doesn't have the app to execute. could you undertand?

Comment: What's wrong with creating a mock which sub-classes BaseCommand?

Comment: Because its an abstract class, and the main operation its in the parent class, in this case XCommand.

Comment: I need to test this. IResult res = new XCommand().Author();

Comment: I think you haven't read what i said. Create a mock which **sub-classes** your abstract base class and returns an arbitrary value from `Run`.

Comment: Could you give an example, will help too much, Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you want to test in `XCommand.Author`? What is currently preventing you from testing it?

Comment: In this method, a process is created, but its about a transaction with svn and i don't have this transaction, because it test is to read some data from svn, if you have a better solution, please help me to built it right.

Comment: Why not make `Author` a virtual method which you can override in a test class?

Comment: Instead of using a base class why not inject a class with the `Run` method?

Comment: this code, will be part of an API, i need to sealed the class, there is another known way?

Comment: how i do this, inject a class with the run method? i didn't understand very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inheriting from the class I would inject it instead using an interface.

```
public sealed class XCommand
{
    IHaveARunMethod runClass;

    public XCommand(IHaveARunMethod classWithRunMethod)
    {
        runClass = classWithRunMethod;
    }

    public IResult Author()
    {
        //DO SOMETHING AND RETURN BASE.

        return runClass.run();
    }        
}

public interface IHaveARunMethod
{
    IResult Run();
}

public class HasRunMethod : IHaveARunMethod
{
    public IResult Run()
    {
        //Your run code here.
    }
}
```

Then you can Mock the `IHaveARunMethod` interface and inject it into the `XCommand` class.

Then you can use it like this

```
var command = new XCommand(CreateMockedOfIHaveARunMethod());
```

You can even create other classes that implement `IHaveARunMethod` so you can inject different behavior if needed.